# Strategy to have latest code from git in Azure Blob or equivalent

Tags: .net, git, azure, asp.net-core

I have a GIT repository with some code that changes frequently. It may change every few minutes.

I have an app running in Azure in an App Service.

I need to be able to access the latest code files in Azure somewhere, conveniently located so my app can always access it. It could be in Azure Blob Storage. To be clear, my app needs to access the actual code files and save them to a database.

What would be a good way to accomplish this in a simple and stable setup?

My current solution is having my app work as a GIT client and get the code directly from the GIT repository, but that has adverse side effects. I always only want the latest code, so that is why I now want to retrieve the code from a simple file system of some sort instead of having my app interact directly with GIT.

Comment: where do you have your git repo hosted?

Comment: It happens to be in Bitbucket, but I need to support it being hosted other places, so the question is about a general GIT repository and not about Bitbucket.

Comment: so why not use web app git integration? it doesnt care where the code is

Comment: @4c74356b41 Will that enable me to get the code files in an Azure Blob Storage or equivalent? Note, I need the actual code files, I am not talking about updating my application with the code from GIT.

Comment: whats the equivalent of azure blob storage? your question is extemely vague and it looks like you dont understand what you want

Comment: I apologize if I did not explain it clearly enough. I have an app hosted in Azure and I would like to be able to access the files from this app. So one convenient place to access the files could be in Azure Blob Storage, but I am open for alternatives. It is vague because Azure Blob Storage is not a requirement, any other convenient way of accessing the latest code files is satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)

This way you will be able run custom scripts whenever code is committed to a certain repository. From here you will be able to checkout the files and store them as needed.

If your code repo is on GitHub, Visual Studio Team Services etc. you can also use Web Hooks to notify your server running somewhere else to checkout the latest code and do the processing.

The way i have achieved this using [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/vso/) is 

1. I Have setup a build service to run every time code is pushed to the `master` branch of my repo.

2. Build Service checkouts the latest code on a webserver.

3. Builds it(Optional)

4. Assigns an automatically generating / Incrementing version no to the code. 

5. Zips the code - Zips the folder on the server to which the latest code has been checked out. 

6. Uploads the Code files and PDB's to a Azure Blob (This is done for bug fixing, testing and debugging in production)

* The Best part is that all the scripts needed to do this is already available at Visual Studio Online and no extra code is needed to be written.*

Comment: Please note, I am not interested in building anything. I just want to grab the actual code. Also, I need a solution that works generically for GIT and not specifically for any platform or GIT host.

Comment: the first part of my answer whenere in i aske you to look for git hooks is language and platform agnostic. 
Building the code is an optional step

Comment: Yes, but having a hook is a secondary wish, so it does not address the primary question in any way.

Comment: i dont know how to define a 'secondary wish' - i hv mentioned 2 types of hooks 1. a hook 2. a web hook. I hope you have read my answer carefully

Comment: Yes I have. My objective is basically item 6 in your list, except I am asking regarding GIT and cannot be linked to a specific provider. But thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explore azcopy options
azcopy sync should be a key for your solution.